# Timestamp in web services

Tags: web-services

A solution to prevent replay attacks in a web service request is to use timestamps which will be integrated in the request.

What's the best way to get a timestamp? Should this be from the client side or to make an initial request for a timestamp, integrate that timestamp to next request, then send the request to the server?

Comment: *This is horrid "security".* A client can fake a timestamp: it's just say "Oh, yeah, it's December 2031" (or whatever). To avoid replays use SSL and/or nonces and/or HMACs (could be over timestamps although that doesn't seem useful) depending upon what sort of reply is being guarded against, etc.

Comment: Yes. That's why I'm not really too keen with the client timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

better to send the gmt time stamp so that it will be converted back to any other time zone at client side.

Comment: So it would be better to generate a timestamp at the client-side then send it to the server? How about issues with incorrect settings?

Comment: Server is the centric place for applications and we have to take the server time converted to GMT and get the time stamp. Generally servers will be maintained with proper time settings.